# i have got error to push new data to array

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, fluent

I am doing to take tree structure.

**I need to add data and want to delete, edit, and search**

When I push new data into an array before that data stored a new var in that data at that time I have got one **error**

```
TypeError: treeData.push is not a function
```

How to set that data into a new var and how to push an array...

**DragandDrop.js**:

```js
import React, {
    useState,
    Component,
    useEffect
} from "react";
import 'react-sortable-tree/style.css';
import {
    removeNodeAtPath
} from 'react-sortable-tree';
import SortableTree from 'react-sortable-tree';
import {
    toggleExpandedForAll
} from 'react-sortable-tree';
import './styles.css'


const Treeview = (props, reset) => {
    console.log('props', props)

    const initTreeData = [{
            title: 'Data_1',
            children: [{
                title: "Data_2"
            }]
        },
        {
            title: 'Data_1'
        },
        {
            title: 'Data_2'
        }
    ]
    console.log('test', initTreeData.length)

    var test = {
        index: initTreeData.length + 1,
        title: props.info
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        _fetchGeneral();
    }, [])

    const [treeData, setTreeData] = useState(initTreeData);

    console.log(treeData, "*******")
    if (test.title != '') {
        var m = treeData.push(test)
        // setTreeData(m);
    }

    const _fetchGeneral = async () => {
        setTreeData(initTreeData);
    }

    const updateTreeData = (e) => {
        setTreeData(e);
    }

    // Expand and collapse code 
    const expand = (expanded) => {
        setTreeData(toggleExpandedForAll({
            treeData: treeData,
            expanded,
        }), );
    }

    const expandAll = () => {
        expand(true);
    }

    const collapseAll = () => {
        expand(false);
    }

    // Expand and collapse code  end

    // remove node 
    const removeNode = (rowInfo) => {
        let {
            node,
            treeIndex,
            path
        } = rowInfo;

        setTreeData(removeNodeAtPath({
            treeData: treeData,
            path: path, // You can use path from here
            getNodeKey: ({
                node: TreeNode,
                treeIndex: number
            }) => {
                console.log(number, 'event');
                return (number);
            },
            ignoreCollapsed: false,
        }))
    }

    // remove node end

    return ( <
        div style = {
            {
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                height: '100vh'
            }
        } >
        <
        div style = {
            {
                flex: '0 0 auto',
                padding: '0 15px'
            }
        } >
        <
        h3 > Full Node Drag Theme < /h3> <
        button onClick = {
            expandAll
        } > Expand All < /button> <
        button onClick = {
            collapseAll
        } > Collapse All < /button> &
        nbsp; & nbsp; & nbsp; & nbsp; & nbsp; & nbsp; & nbsp; & nbsp;


        <
        /div>

        <
        div style = {
            {
                flex: '1 0 50%',
                padding: '0 0 0 15px'
            }
        } >
        <
        SortableTree className = "tree-dt"
        id = "add_name"
        treeData = {
            treeData
        }
        onChange = {
            updateTreeData
        }
        generateNodeProps = {
            rowInfo => ({
                buttons: [ <
                    div >
                    <
                    button label = 'Delete'
                    onClick = {
                        () => removeNode(rowInfo)
                    } > X < /button> < /
                    div > ,
                ],
                style: {
                    height: '50px',
                }
            })
        }
        canDrag = {
            ({
                node
            }) => !node.dragDisabled
        }
        /> < /
        div > <
        /div>
    );
}

export default Treeview;
```

**Add.js File**:

```js
import React, {
    useState
} from 'react';
import {
    TextField
} from '@fluentui/react/lib/TextField';
import {
    DefaultButton,
    PrimaryButton,
    Stack,
    IStackTokens
} from '@fluentui/react';
import './styles.css'


const TextFieldBasicExample = (props) => {
    const [newItemValue, setNewItemValue] = useState({
        title: ''
    });
    console.log('onchange', newItemValue);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setNewItemValue({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        });
    }
    const _insert = (event) => {
        console.log('onclick', newItemValue);
        props.callback(newItemValue);

        // setNewItem({
        //   [event.target.name]:''
        // })
    }

    return ( <
        Stack horizontal >
        <
        Stack className = "add-inp" >

        <
        TextField label = "Add Item"
        name = "title"
        onChange = {
            handleChange
        }
        /> <
        span id = "error_name" > < /span> <
        PrimaryButton text = "Add"
        className = "add-btn"
        onClick = {
            _insert
        }
        />

        <
        /Stack> <
        /Stack>


    );
};

export default TextFieldBasicExample
```

**app.js file**:

```js
import React, {
    useState,
    Component,
    useEffect
} from "react";
import 'react-sortable-tree/style.css';
import TreeView from "./Drag&Drop";
// import Test from "./Testing";
import AddEdit from "./Add";
import './styles.css'

const Tree = (props) => {
    const [info, setInfo] = useState('');
    const data = (item) => {
        let value = item.title;
        setInfo(value);
    }
    console.log('data', info)
    return ( <
        div >
        <
        div className = "add-dt" >
        <
        div className = "left-side" >
        <`enter code here`
        AddEdit callback = {
            data
        }
        /> <
        /div> <
        div className = "right-side" >
        <
        TreeView info = {
            info
        }
        /> <
        /div> <
        /div> 

        <
        /div>
    );
}

export default Tree;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are facing issue with this code snippet:

```
    if (test.title != '') {
    var m = treeData.push(test)
    // setTreeData(m);
    }
```

so you can do it like this:

```
if (test.title != '') {
    setTreeData([...treeData, test]);
    }
```

Comment: I tried this... But again I got a console error...           (react-dom.development.js:14815 Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.  )

Comment: debug your code a bit more cause this is how i have been adding items and it works fine for me.there must be something else which is causing this issue.

Comment: i tested it in my VS code(only treeData code) and it correctly adds data to treeData

Comment: when I click the add button after given input my all the tree data will be hide and render more times an array( console error)...

Comment: I got data in console... but cannot show that data in my tree and also any event happened in my tree data that time only newly adding more time on every event...

Comment: data push functionality will render before that my tree data functions running...  I have more confused... can you give any solutions for me...

Comment: can you paste your code in https://codesandbox.io/ so that i can see the live demo ? and debug accordingly

Comment: ok... I will paste my code in codesandbox.io

Comment: i put this code in useEffect after that working clearly... thanks to Sakshi...

Comment: hi... this is my code sandbox link hi,
hi, I got the error to run my project on code sandbox...  
I would attach my live link below...

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-bogdan-7p2mg?file=/src/index.js

Anyone help me to run my project clearly...

Answer (score 0):

try useState<string[]>(defaultValues) or useState([])

Comment: I don't know how to put this code... can you please give a detailed example for me...